# Vectorizing multiple vector-matrix multiplications in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I am having trouble figuring out how to arrange my axes so I can perform the following operations in a vectorized way.

Essentially I have an array of vectors, an array of matrices, and I want to evaluate VMV^T for each corresponding vector V and matrix M

```
import numpy as np

N = 5 # normally 100k or so
vecs = np.random.rand(N, 2)
mats = np.random.rand(N, 2, 2)

output = np.array([np.dot(np.dot(vecs[i, ...], mats[i, ...]), vecs[i, ...].T) for i in range(N)])
```

If it's simpler, vectorizing the intermediate result below would also be helpful:

```
intermediate_result = np.array([np.dot(vecs[i, ...], mats[i, ...]) for i in range(N)])
# then I can do
output = np.sum(intermediate_result * vecs, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `einsum`-based solution is 100x faster than your loop for N = 100k:

```
%timeit np.array([np.dot(np.dot(vecs[i, ...], mats[i, ...]), vecs[i, ...].T) for i in range(N)])
%timeit np.einsum('...i,...ij,...j->...', vecs, mats, vecs)
np.allclose(np.array([np.dot(np.dot(vecs[i, ...], mats[i, ...]), vecs[i, ...].T) for i in range(N)]),
            np.einsum('...i,...ij,...j->...', vecs, mats, vecs))
1 loops, best of 3: 640 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.02 ms per loop
Out[45]: True
```

Comment: Yeah, `einsum` is amazing: compact notation, really fast and flexible!